# Get user privileges on item via Sitecore RESTful API

Tags: webapi, permissions

I am looking for a good way to figure out what privileges a user has via the Sitecore RESTful API.

For example, I can use the RESTful API for [ItemService](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice):

```
/sitecore/api/ssc/item/{itemId}?fields=__Security&database=master&includeStandardTemplateFields=true
```

This allows me to get the security string set directly on an item and looks like this:

```
"__Security": "au|sitecore\\User|pe|+item:read|+item:rename|"
```

However, if the user has rights to that item that are inherited from the parent, it does not show up in the __Security field.

Is there another way I can use the Sitecore RESTful API to determine which privileges a user has on a Sitecore item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore security model does provide API for determining user access rights (see `Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess` class). AFAIK there is no any web service exposing it but you can easily create one using [Sitecore Services Client](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/sitecoreservicesclient):

```
public class AccessController : ServicesApiController
{
    [Route("sitecore/api/ssc/itemaccess/{database}/{itemId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string database, string itemId)
    {
        // simplified. no null check
        var item = Database.GetDatabase(database).GetItem(itemId);
        var model = new ItemAccessDto
        {
            CanRead = item.Access.CanRead(),
            CanWrite = item.Access.CanWrite(),
            CanCreate = item.Access.CanCreate(),
            CanDelete = item.Access.CanDelete(),
        };

        return Ok(model);
    }

    private class ItemAccessDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("can_read")]
        public bool CanRead { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("can_write")]
        public bool CanWrite { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("can_create")]
        public bool CanCreate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("can_delete")]
        public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now you can request user access info. That is what an anonymous user can do with the default Home item:

```
http://mysite/sitecore/api/ssc/itemaccess/master/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9

Result:
{
    "can_read": true,
    "can_write": false,
    "can_create": false,
    "can_delete": false
}
```